# How to print values of all elements of java.util.Date type Array in R language

Tags: java, arrays, r

I am new in **R language** and i have a problem :

In java i have a method like this

```
public Date[] getAllDates(String fromDate, String toDate){
        ArrayList<Date> dates= new ArrayList<Date>();
            -------
      Generating dates from fromDate to toDate here and setting into above
      arraylist.
            ------

           return dates.toArray(dates.size());

}
```

Now in **R** when i am calling this method then it is returning this array

```
dates= c(classInstance$getAllDates(fromDate,toDate));
```

Now i am not able to show the dates values present in dates array it is showing as object only.

**Case : 1**
and if i use `print(str(dates[1]))` then it displays

```
List of 1
 $ :Formal class 'jrectRef' [package "rJava"] with 4 slots
  .. ..@ dimension: int 10
  .. ..@ jsig     : chr "[Ljava/util/Date;"
  .. ..@ jobj     :<externalptr> 
  .. ..@ jclass   : chr "[Ljava/util/Date;"
NULL
```

when i use : `print(typeof(dates[1]))`

it is showing

```
"S4"
```

**Case : 2**
when i use : `print(typeof(dates[1]))`

it is showing

```
"list"
```

i tried everything but i am not able to show the values from this array.
please help me.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after a lot of search on google(approx 3 days continuously) about R programming and concept and techniques to resolve my above issue, now i am able to give my answer itself.

```
dates= c(classInstance$getAllDates(fromDate,toDate));
```

from here

**Case : 1 Solution**

```
for(i in 1 : dates$length) { 
 #Fetching one by one date object using for each loop in R
 index = .jevalArray(dates)[[i]]
 # Holding an individual array into variable 
 print(index$toString())
 # Now printing using Java toString() method only.
 }
```

Note** : but for "list" type this solution also got stuck. It worked for me when typeof was "S4"

**Case : 2 Solution**

I found a working solution for this as well

```
arraysObject = .jnew("java/util/Arrays")

#Just taken a reference of an object of java Arrays classes
for (i in 1:length(indexes[[1]])){      
        print(arraysObject$toString(indexes[[1]][i]))       
#calling Arrays.toString() method of java into R programming
    }
```

**OR**

```
arraysObject = .jnew("java/util/Arrays")
print(arraysObject$toString(indexes[[1]]))
```